# How to format partitions which previously was allocated to a different distro?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I was using Manjaro for years then I decided to try Ubuntu, so I dual booted Manjaro and Ubuntu. Now I want to extend the storage size for ubutnu but I'm getting failure everytime. I'm using "Gparted" for managing partitions. 
It can't format that partition which was previously allocated to Manjaro. Help me out. Ask me if you any additional informations. Thank You

Comment: Are you using `gparted` from a live running system, or when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Edit your question and show us a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: The results of 'sudo parted -l' would also be helpful.

Comment: You must boot from a Live USB. If any of a disk's partitions is mounted, `gparted` won't change the disk.